# Reformat paragraph with no breaking characters in Vim

Tags: vim

I typically use `gq` with the appropriate `format-options` and `textwidth` settings to format lines to wrap at particular widht. E.g, with `textwidth=10`, typing `gqq` or `gql` on the following line:

```
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
```

changes it to:

```
the quick
brown fox
jumps over
the lazy
dog
```

But how do you achieve a similar formatting when there are no natural breaks:

E.g.

```
AAACCCTTGGGAGGGGAGGTTTGGGAGTTGGAHCTTGGAGGA
```

More generally, what if you do *not* want Vim to try and break on words but unconditionally wrap at a particular width?

The only way I could achieve this is by:

```
:set formatprg=par\ -w10
```

followed by `gql`.

This works like a charm, but I was wondering if there was a way to do this using just Vim by some combination of format-options etc.

Comment: `:.!par -w10` is IMO the most "UNIX-y" (and thus "Vim-y") way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special `\%v` regular expression atom to match at a particular column, and then use `:substitute` to insert a line break (`\r`) there.

```
:%s/\%11v/\r/g
```

This needs to be applied repeatedly to split the entire long line. Alternatively, you can enumerate all split points and do this in one go:

```
:s/\%11v\|\%21v\|\%31v\|\%41v/\r/g
```

Comment: This is so much more complicated than `par`, but it does the job natively, as requested, and it seems that there is no easier way!

Comment: Nothing prevents you from making the invocation as simple by writing a short `:Par` command that builds the regexp for you.

Comment: Of course. But once I am going to write a custom function/command, then anything is possible. I was hoping for something a few key maps away. By the way, I use your FormatToWidth plugin, and really like it!